# Tuning a query converting subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, subquery

I was trying to change an update statement where there is a subquery in the WHERE clause to a join in order to improve performance. 
DDL to sample table/data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
[pre_plan_id] [smallint] NULL,
[pre_type_id] [smallint] NULL,
[associate_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[deleted] [bit] NOT NULL
)  

INSERT INTO Table1 
VALUES 
(NULL,  NULL,   -32768, 0),
(1,  NULL,   2,  1),
(1,  NULL,   3,  0), 
(NULL, NULL, 3109, 0), 
(1, NULL, 3109, 1) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
[type_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[plan_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[associate_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[time_in] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL
) 
INSERT INTO Table2 
VALUES
(390,   31, 3109,   '2009-09-02'),
(304,   32, 3109,   '2010-02-05'),
(388,   31, 3109,   '2010-09-24')
```

The query that uses a subquery:

```
SELECT pre_plan_id, pre_type_id FROM Table1  WHERE pre_plan_id =1 
AND associate_id  NOT IN 
(SELECT TOP 2 associate_id 
FROM Table2 WHERE time_in= '2010-09-24 00:00:00' group by associate_id order by count(*) desc)
```

My attempt of converting it to JOIN

```
SELECT pre_plan_id 
FROM (SELECT pre_plan_id, pre_type_id, rn
FROM Table1 a  
LEFT JOIN 
( select associate_id, Row_number() over (partition by associate_id order by count(*) desc ) rn 
FROM Table2 
WHERE time_in= '2010-09-24 00:00:00' Group by associate_id) b 
ON a.associate_id = b.associate_id where b.rn <> 1) a
where pre_plan_id = 1
```

However, this displays nothing while I expect two rows; and it is happening because of b.rn <> 1 
 I expected it would display the NULL values when it is b.rn <> 1

Any explanation for this? Any guide on better approach of tuning the query is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move the subquery to the `FROM` clause and use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.pre_plan_id, t1.pre_type_id
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 2 t2.associate_id 
      FROM Table2
      WHERE t2.time_in= '2010-09-24 00:00:00' 
      GROUP BY associate_id 
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
     ) t2
     ON t2.associate_id = t1.associate_id
WHERE t1.pre_plan_id = 1 AND t2.associate_id IS NULL;
```